# Postgres: index on multiple column with different leading column

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-performance

I have two indexes of two columns:

```
create index idx_film_length_rating on film (length, rating);
create index idx_film_rating_length on film (rating, length);
```

When I execute:

```
explain analyze select title, length, rating, replacement_cost, rental_rate
from film
where rating = 'G' and length between 60 and 70
```

The postgres think idx_film_rating_length is always the best option, and use this index. But why if there's no second index, idx_film_rating_length, the query will get slower? For my understanding, the execution plans are the same, extract blocks are the same, they should be the same.

The result with only one index is:

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on film  (cost=4.44..35.70 rows=13 width=34) (actual time=0.102..0.120 rows=18 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: ((rating = 'G'::mpaa_rating) AND (length >= 60) AND (length <= 70))"
"  Heap Blocks: exact=14"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_film_rating_length  (cost=0.00..4.44 rows=13 width=0) (actual time=0.095..0.095 rows=18 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: ((rating = 'G'::mpaa_rating) AND (length >= 60) AND (length <= 70))"
"Planning time: 0.316 ms"
"Execution time: 0.160 ms"
```

And result with two indexes in the table:

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on film  (cost=4.44..35.70 rows=13 width=34) (actual time=0.030..0.041 rows=18 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: ((rating = 'G'::mpaa_rating) AND (length >= 60) AND (length <= 70))"
"  Heap Blocks: exact=14"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_film_rating_length  (cost=0.00..4.44 rows=13 width=0) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=18 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: ((rating = 'G'::mpaa_rating) AND (length >= 60) AND (length <= 70))"
"Planning time: 0.199 ms"
"Execution time: 0.065 ms"
```

You can see though the plans are the same, the second one is faster.

======================================
Recommended by @a_horse_with_no_name
After add buffers and details:

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on film  (cost=4.44..35.70 rows=13 width=34) (actual time=0.692..0.716 rows=18 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: ((rating = 'G'::mpaa_rating) AND (length >= 60) AND (length <= 70))"
"  Heap Blocks: exact=14"
"  Buffers: shared hit=14 read=2"
"  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_film_cover  (cost=0.00..4.44 rows=13 width=0) (actual time=0.680..0.680 rows=18 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: ((rating = 'G'::mpaa_rating) AND (length >= 60) AND (length <= 70))"
"        Buffers: shared read=2"
"Planning time: 1.773 ms"
"Execution time: 1.441 ms"
```

It seems problem might associate with:
" Buffers: shared hit=14 read=2"?

Comment: Use `explain (analyze, buffers, timing)` to see more details and pin-point the differences

Comment: Thanks, I've just added the result with buffers and timing.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the plans are identical.

The difference in execution time is just coincidental. Perhaps more of the index was cached the second time.

Repeat the `EXPLAIN` several times to get statistically relevant results.

Comment: There're no variance... only one result.

Comment: I am talking about the variance in execution time. As you suspect, the *buffers read* make the difference.